# Should database theory questions be posted here, in cstheory or in cs?

Tags: discussion, support

As per title, it doesn't seem to be clear.

As an aside, maybe for similar situations you should add a feature to allow to add a link to the question on the questions pane of the closely related groups, these being chosen by the user at the moment of the creation of the question (maybe also in succeeding edits).
It's only going to become more complex as you add groups otherwise.

Comment: There are already many SQL and DBMS questions on SO that could just as well be asked here. Should we move the lot over? I think there is overlap between various SE sites and there's not much that can be done about it.

Comment: For sure, I think that limiting the separation by allowing questions to be listed in multiple sites would help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, database theory questions should be asked here. You could equally likely post them to CSTheory if the FAQ matches.

However, as with all questions, it has to meet the requirements for objective questions.

Cheers.